# Angular setar valor em radio button

Tags: javascript, java, angular

Tenho um campo no formulário com buttons radio:

```
<div class="form-group" >
     <label class="control-label col-md-4">Tipo Atividade2*:</label>
     <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="atividadeFixa" value="true" required> Fixa<br>
     <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="atividadeFixa" value="false" required> Não Fixa<br>
</div>
```

Preciso Carregar o valor quem vem do back para o front. De que forma posso fazer isso ?

**código do objeto:**

```
export class Atividade {

    atividadeFixa: boolean
}
```

**codigo service**

```
editarAtividade(atividade : Atividade) : Observable<any>{
        //return Observable.of("Edition not implemented yet")
        let params = this.setParamsAtividade(atividade)
        params.set("atividade", atividade.id.toString())
return this.http.doPut(Rotas.ATIVIDADE, params)
}
```

Comment: Qual versão do angular vc está usando?

Comment: Estou usando a versão do angular 6.0

Comment: Fazer uma string interpolation n resolve? `value="{{valor}}"`

Comment: [checked] = atividade.atividadefixa; pode resolver ??

Comment: Você quer `checar` o rado button de acordo com o que vem do back? Se for, como vem esse valor do back?

Comment: isso mesmo. A duvida esta no valor que vem do back

Comment: E como vem esse valor?

Comment: o valor tipo boolean

Answer (score 1):

Como você está usando ngModel só alterar o valor da propriedade `atividadeFixa`.

Fiz no stackblitz um exemplo com `setTimeout()` e alterando o valor dela isso meio que simula um request.

[Exemplo StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfztdq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Felipe Carlos seja bem vindo...

Comment: Como transformo seu trecho em funcao no angular ?

Comment: é só vc criar um método e alterar o valor do ngModel nele